# How can I set the LocationID on the 'Create Shipment' process from the Sales Orders screen?

Tags: acumatica

I have a process that creates records in the Sales Orders screen's Details grid based on two Header user fields:  SiteID (Warehouse) and LocationID.

When the 'Create Shipment' process is initiated, the shipment is created which contains the SiteID in the Sales Orders grid - but since there is no locationID in the grid, this 'Create Shipment' process uses some  default(?) LocationID, where I'd like to use the Header User field's LocationID.

My question is, how would I intercept this process to set the LocationID to something other than what it's defaulting to?

Thanks...

Update:

Using the virtual method:

```
   SetShipmentFieldsFromOrder(SOOrder order, SOShipment shipment, Nullable<Int32> siteID, Nullable<DateTime> shipDate, String operation, SOOrderTypeOperation orderOperation, Boolean newlyCreated, SetShipmentFieldsFromOrderDelegate baseMethod)
```

I don't see any way to set the grid value for LocationID (i.e., there is no SOShipLine record to set a value in the virtual method.   How would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

There's a virtual method on the SOShipmentEntry graph called SetShipmentFieldsFromOrder, you can override that to update the CustomerLocationID as needed. The create shipment action calls SOShipmentEntry.CreateShipment which inserts the shipment and then calls the SetShipmentFieldsFromOrder method.

The system should be pulling the SOShipment.CustomerLocationID from the SOOrder.CustomerLocationID field by default though.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the question is about defaulting of warehouse locations into the shipment lines and allocations rather than customer locations

Currently, shipment line selects location(s) by the following way

1. Originally (SelectLocationStatus), it selects location based on their pick priority (smaller value means higher priority)
2. After this method, the ResortStockForShipmentByDefaultItemLocation is executed. This method puts the default issue location for the item-warehouse combination (InItemSite) at the top of this list regardless of its pick priority.
   I believe you should override this method to put the needed location to the top of the list instead of (or ahead of) the default issue location. Here is the code of this method of the SOShipmentEntry class for reference:

   ```
         protected virtual void ResortStockForShipmentByDefaultItemLocation(SOShipLine newline, List<PXResult> resultset)

            if (INSite.PK.Find(this, newline.SiteID)?.UseItemDefaultLocationForPicking != true)
                return;

            var dfltShipLocationID = INItemSite.PK.Find(this, newline.InventoryID, newline.SiteID)?.DfltShipLocationID;
            if (dfltShipLocationID == null)
                return;

            var listOrderedByDfltShipLocationID = resultset.OrderByDescending(
                r => PXResult.Unwrap<INLocation>(r).LocationID == dfltShipLocationID).ToList();
            resultset.Clear();
            resultset.AddRange(listOrderedByDfltShipLocationID);
        }
   ```

**Important**!   If we are talking about 21R2 version, there is the "Project-Specific Inventory" (materialManagement) feature which has its own extension of the SOShipmentEntry where some of the shipment creation methods (including the SelectLocationStatus) are overridden. The ResortStockForShipmentByDefaultItemLocation is not overridden, but if the customer uses this feature, I suggest to extend this extension rather than base SOSHipmentEntry:

```
namespace PX.Objects.PM.MaterialManagement
{
    public class SOShipmentEntryMaterialExt : PXGraphExtension<SOShipmentEntry>
```